# Using multiple criteria with VLOOKUP

Tags: vba

I've 2 Tables:

```
              TYPE A        
VARIABLES   A1  A2  A3
VAR 1           
VAR 2           
VAR 3           
VAR 4


              TYPEB     
VARIABLES   A1  A2  A3
VAR 1                   
VAR 3           
VAR 4
```

I want to create a vba code such that it will vlookup and populate the data in the following format:

```
             TYPE A     TYPE B  
VARIABLES   A1  A2  A3  A1  A3
VAR 1                   
VAR 2                   
VAR 3                   
VAR 4
```

I can use vlookup vba code which have single criteria and populate the tables. But can we have the code that can do it with multiple criterion.

The following code I was trying to do for each table. But this is cumbersome as I've to right code like for each table. If the number of tables are large then it's very cumbersome. I tried to see if there's any example over internet, but unfortunately didn't get any.

```
Sub VlookUpExample()

Dim rw As Long
For rw = 2 To 4
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rw, 2) = Application.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rw, 1), _
    Sheets("Pivot").Columns("B:I"), 2, False)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rw, 3) = Application.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rw, 1), _
    Sheets("Pivot").Columns("B:I"), 3, False)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rw, 4) = Application.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rw, 1), _
    Sheets("Pivot").Columns("B:I"), 4, False)

Next
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: I read that with index match, I can do this kind of work. But didn't get any example of VBA code for index match. If somebody can give me a reference that will be great too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make many criteria using simple "if then". When you want to add another criteria just type next "if then" below "else".

```
If *some condition* Then
    *do something*

    Else
    *do something else*

End If
```

Comment: Thanks Iowak! I'll try on your hint.